# Return Brief description

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, webforms

I have a simple search and i want to return a very brief part of the description. I want to grab the first 200 characters of `i.Description`. What is the best way of doing this?

```
  (
                      i.ItemName.Contains(keyword) ||
                      i.Email.Contains(keyword) ||
                      i.Description.Contains(keyword) ||
                      i.ItemID.Equals(searchID)
                      )
                         select new
                         {

                             Name = i.ItemName,
                             Phone = i.Phone,
                             Type = i.Type,
                             Email = i.Email,
                             ID = i.ItemID,
                             Desc = i.Description
                             // I was hoping i could do with a .Length or something    

                         });
```

Comment: If you are going to perform a expensive operation like this you should simply show the entire decription.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this to make it not so expensive?

Comment: I assume its a SQl query of some kind, so the query itself, is expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Desc = i.Description.SubString(0, Math.Min(i.Description.Length, 200))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Take` method:

```
Desc = new string(i.Description.Take(200).ToArray());
```